# Read lines from a file and tokenize each line to extract specific word in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I wrote a shell script to read all lines from a file, tokenized each line to extract particular word.
First line is read correct, but from the second line the expected word is not reading correctly. Looking forward for your suggestions.

```
while read -ra line; 
    do
        netmask="${line[5]}"
        echo "netmask is $netmask" // first line reading is correct, second line onwards its showing 
                                      wrong output
        IFS='.' tokens=($netmask) 
        prefix=0
        for i in 0 1 2 3
        do
            var="${tokens[$i]}"
            # i have a logic to calculate number of 1's in the number.
        done 
done < routes.sh
```

Contents of route.sh are

```
route add -net 10.212.220.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.213.248.1
route add -net 10.212.220.0 netmask 255.255.128.0 gw 10.213.248.1
```

Actual output

```
netmask is 255.255.255.0
netmask is 128
```

Expected output

```
netmask is 255.255.255.0
netmask is 255.255.128.0
```

Extra Note:

My objective is to (network concept)

1. Read all lines from a file (each line depicts a route)
2. From each line extract the netmask (e.g.: 255.255.255.255)
3. Tokenize "255.255.255.255" with '.', so we get 4 numbers, calculate the number of 1s in each 
       token, add them up. That would be prefix length for the network IP.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't had enough points to vote or accept the solutions. Sorry, i didnt used stackoverflow much earlier as i was doing manual testing. Now got some opportunity to code  and automate.

Comment: No problem. It was just a friendly advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set `IFS='.'`, so for the second `read` on the array `line` will be incorrectly set.

One way to fix it is by saving the original `IFS` and then resetting it when appropriate. For example,

```
OldIFS=$IFS
while read -ra line; do
    netmask="${line[5]}"
    echo "netmask is $netmask"
    IFS='.' tokens=($netmask)
    prefix=0
    for i in 0 1 2 3; do
        var="${tokens[$i]}"
    done
    IFS=$OldIFS
done < routes.sh
```

You must be careful when changing `IFS`, otherwise weird things will happen.